# Galton Box Probability

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Hey guys I'm writing a program for homework to display the path of a ball in a Galton box

[image: galton box]

My program so far picks how many balls you want to drop, and the amount of slots at the bottom of the box, and the shows you the random path the ball takes.

The issue I ran into is that if the amount of balls are greater than or equal to the amount of slots in the box the program doesn't run fully and I get this error

```
Enter the amount of balls to drop: 
8
Enter the amount of slots: 
8

LRLLRRR
RLRLLLR
RLRLLLL
RLLLLRR
RLRRRLL
RRLRRRR
LLLRRRR
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at Set_8_P6_21.main(Set_8_P6_21.java:35)
```

So I was wondering if anyone could explain why this is happening...thanks!

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class Set_8_P6_21 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int balls, slots;

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of balls to drop: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        balls = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of slots: ");
        slots = input.nextInt();

        char[] arrayslot = new char[slots-1];

        for (int i = 0; i < balls; i++) {
            System.out.println();

            for (int j = 0; j < slots-1; j++) {

                double k = Math.random();

                if (k < 0.5)
                    arrayslot[i] = 'L';

                else if (k >= 0.5)
                    arrayslot[i] = 'R';

                System.out.print(arrayslot[i]);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If there's an error message then post it here, not a screen shot of it somewhere else.

Comment: You declare `arrayslot` with a length of `slots-1`, but then you access it with `arrayslot[i]`, where `i` goes from `0` to `balls-1` (see your first `for` loop).

Comment: FYI: Don't use the snippet button to add code blocks that aren't executable javascript. The `{}` button is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` goes as high as the number of balls.  `arrayslots` is as big as the number of slots.  But you make reference to arrayslots[i], so if the number of balls exceeds the number of slots you will get this error.

You should probably be referencing arrayslots[j] instead.